# Using math symbols within lstlisting

Tags: emacs

I am using `$` and `_` symbols within `lstlisting` environment and the output pdf looks OK but I am having an issue within emacs editor where the occurrence of `$` changes the colour of the whole document and the occurrence of `_` (after `$`) is also producing undesired results within the editor.

How can I suppress the interpretation of `$` as start of math expression? I have tried escaping `$` as `\$` but in the output pdf, I am getting `\$` which is not required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  a$ = b$ + c$;
  a_{d}=a_{c}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have `(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Verbatim" "lstlisting"))` in my `.emacs` file, so both `Verbatim` and `lstlisting` are considered like `verbatim`.

Comment: I think you should change the title, the problem is not with `lstlisting` but with `emacs` and its coloring system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Aquamacs, so AUCTeX is automatically loaded.

After adding

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments '("Verbatim" "lstlisting"))
```

to my `Preferences.el` file (the analog of `.emacs` or whatever initialization file you use), the `lstlisting` environment is considered the same as `verbatim` as far as coloring and fonts are concerned. Since I often use `Verbatim` from `fancyvrb`, I added that as well.

[image]

Comment: Your AUCTeX should load `listings.el` automatically which contains `(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "lstlisting")`. Same goes for `fancyvrb.el`; your addition to `Preferences.el` should not be necessary.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Nice to know; is it a recent addition to AUCTeX? As far as I know, those `.el` files are not automatically loaded.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I tried with a standard Emacs, with AUCTeX loaded and no, those `.el` files are not loaded.

Comment: Actually not. AUCTeX is supporting styles for a long time. I presume something is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: @ArashEsbati On two different flavors of Emacs both using AUCTeX? Sorry, I can't accept this.

Comment: I'm not on Mac, so please bear with me. You could try the following in standard Emacs: Install AUCTeX from elpa, comment out `(load "auctex.el" nil t t)` in your init file, restart emacs and load a tex-file.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Did what you said. No listings.el loaded, sorry.

Comment: This is strange, it should work out of the box. Does it help if you open your tex-file an hit `C-u C-c C-n` with the newly installed AUCTeX?

Comment: @ArashEsbati Yes, after the magic it works. And it seems permanent. Please, add an answer, with all details.

Comment: Puh, good to know that it works :-) I presume you don't have `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in your init file. If you add it, AUCTeX loads all used styles when you load a tex file, no `C-c C-n` needed then.

Comment: `LaTeX-verbatim-environments` is meant to be customizable (and so modified by the user), `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local` is not ;-)

Comment: @giordano That's not what I understand from the documentation. Probably my fault, or maybe not?

Comment: @egreg - If you are talking about the AUCTeX manual, it doesn't help in this case; you have to go through the doc-strings.

Comment: @egreg  In the [AUCTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html) `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local` is not even mentioned (for a reason), where did you get that idea?  Arash is right, looking at the doc-strings you can see `LaTeX-verbatim-environments` is customizable and `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local` is not.

Comment: @giordano I understood the *exact contrary*. What the arcane “doc-strings” are, I don't know. Don't be surprised if people thinks Emacs is too arcane. It wouldn't be if the developers used a clearer language.

Comment: @egreg  `C-h v` followed by a variable name shows you the help of that variable.  The "doc-string" (or "documentation string") is what follows the "Documentation:" line.  If there is a "You can customize this variable." line, it means that variable is user-exposed and can be easily customized also using a graphic interface.  Try with `C-h v LaTeX-verbatim-environments RET` and `C-h v LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local RET`.

Comment: @giordano That's what I saw: `Programs should not use this variable directly`; which is now clearer. But it shows that one should buy a dictionary Emacs-English for understanding what's the matter here.

Comment: @egreg - I agree with you that some doc-strings are not that self-explanatory.

Comment: For current Ubuntu versions, this line has to go into `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Answer (score 2):

Upon @egreg's request, I try to be more verbose on this. I assume you are using GNU Emacs; if so, your OS shouldn't make a difference.

## Installation

I suggest you install the latest version of AUCTeX from ELPA by doing <kbd>M-x list-packages RET</kbd>, move the cursor on auctex (version 11.88.4 as writing), hit <kbd>i</kbd> followed by <kbd>x</kbd> and you have the latest version installed (probably under `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`)

## Activation

If installed from ELPA, you must not, I repeat, must not have this in your init file:

```lisp
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
```

AUCTeX is installed and should start as soon as you load a file with `.tex` extension.

## Basic customization

AUCTeX's strength is in supporting basic LaTeX and contributed packages. Currently, more than 180 style files (jargon for "name-of-supported-LaTeX-package.el") are available. AUCTeX can parse your input file and load the right style if you put this in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Otherwise, you have to hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> afterwards. Keep that in your init file.

AUCTeX manual suggests also:

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

It's up to you; I have only the second line in my `.emacs`.

## Usage

Now, you can hit <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> and AUCTeX offers `lstlisting` in completion and asks you for key-value options. Further, note that Emacs doesn't indent the content since spaces are significant:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
a$ = b$ + c$;
a_{d}=a_{c}
\end{lstlisting}
```

The fontification (aka syntax highlighting) should work as well.