# AuCTeX startup is slow

Tags: auctex

I have Emacs 24.4 with AuCTeX 11.88, running on windows 8.1, on a strong computer.

Any time I run emacs, opening the first tex file takes 6 seconds, even if the tex file empty.
This happens either when the tex file is the first file I open, or if emacs is already running (on a non-tex file).
Opening a large non-tex file is very fast. This is why I suspect the culprit is AuCTeX.
Opening the second tex file is also fast, even if I close the first tex file.

I ran the cpu profiler to see where most time is spent:

```
- command-execute                                                  44  70%
 - call-interactively                                              44  70%
  - find-file                                                      27  43%
   - find-file-noselect                                            27  43%
    - find-file-noselect-1                                         27  43%
     - after-find-file                                             27  43%
      - normal-mode                                                25  40%
       - funcall                                                   25  40%
         - set-auto-mode                                           25  40%
          - set-auto-mode-0                                        25  40%
           - tex-mode                                              24  38%
            - apply                                                21  33%
             - TeX-tex-mode                                        21  33%
              - latex-mode                                         15  24%
               - apply                                             15  24%
                - TeX-latex-mode                                   15  24%
                 + LaTeX-common-initialization                      6   9%
                 + byte-code                                        3   4%
                 + LaTeX-maybe-install-toolbar                      2   3%
                 + file-truename                                    1   1%
                 + custom-declare-variable                          1   1%
                 + defvar                                           1   1%
                 + TeX-run-mode-hooks                               1   1%
              + byte-code                                           5   8%
              + file-truename                                       1   1%
            + byte-code                                             3   4%
      + run-hooks                                                   2   3%
  - menu-find-file-existing                                        16  25%
   - find-file-read-args                                           16  25%
    - read-file-name                                               16  25%
       read-file-name-default                                      16  25%
```

Comment: Check the disccusion [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/5745).  If that applies to you, install the latest version from ELPA and see if that helps.

Comment: All I could find is the file `auctex-11.88.6.tar` which I believe is not for windows (in [here](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/auctex.html])).
How can I know if it applies to me?

I added emacs profiler output.

Comment: How did you install AUCTeX?

Comment: Using [the windows site of AuCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html). They have version 11.88, but that fix is in version 11.88.5 forward, which seems to be available for Unix-based OS only.

Comment: Try and uninstall that package, and then install AUCTeX using the Emacs builtin package manager with `M-x package-install RET auctex RET`.  Please, reply to messages here starting with `@username`, with `username` being the user you want to address, otherwise he/she won't be notified.

Comment: @giordano That worked, thanks! Load time is now down to 3 seconds, much more reasonable.
Can I give you and Arash Esbati credit for answering?

I previously installed AUCTeX by unpacking the zip file in my emacs 24.4 directory, as instructed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html).

Comment: @ArashEsbati  see above, I think you should write down an answer `;-)`

Comment: @giordano - Thnx, done `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is addressed in AUCTeX 11.88.5. (the micro version number .5 refers to ELPA version).  Emacs has built-in capabilities to install packages from ELPA.  You can find more detailed information about installation from ELPA [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241105/76063).  When you install AUCTeX from ELPA, it is crucial **not to have** the following line in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
```