# TeXstudio : Error in fontlock (disable syntax highlighting) in a newenvironment that extends from verbatim environment

Tags: environments, texstudio, verbatim

I'm using TeXstudio 2.11 on windows 8.1 and have problems with a syntax highlighting when I use math symbols in a new environment:

My Code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{languagebat}{\VerbatimEnvironment\minted[
    frame=single, 
    xleftmargin=0mm, 
    numbersep=5pt, 
    autogobble, 
    breaklines,  
    breakanywhere, 
    breaklines, 
    framesep=2mm, 
    rulecolor=black!30, 
    bgcolor=black!3, 
    linenos=false, 
    startinline, 
    tabsize=4
    ]{bat}}{\endminted}

\begin{document}

    \begin{languagebat}
        $ git rm --cached giant_file
    \end{languagebat}

\end{document}
```

Result in the editor:

[image]

I think the `languagebat` environment extends from verbatim environment correctly and that should be working fine.

The problem seems to be the `$` sign in the `languagebat` environment, and TeXstudio believes that I have entered some math code that I have not yet terminated with an ending `$` sign. Is there a way to tell TeXstudio to ignore syntax highlighting within a particular environment?

---

- They had the same problem but I don't understand how to fix it in TeXstudio: [Using math symbols within lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241048/using-math-symbols-within-lstlisting)

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat emptor: I'm not a TXS user*

Emacs, the editor you are referring to in the other answer, can parse .tex files and add newly defined commands/environments to its completion list on fly.  I don't think that TXS has this feature, hence you have to write your own .cwl file.  The way I get it you have to put your `minted` related (and other?) code in a .sty file, say `mydefs.sty`, e.g.

```
\ProvidesPackage{mydefs}[2016/11/13 Package mydefs]
\RequirePackage{minted}
\newenvironment{languagebat}{\VerbatimEnvironment\minted[
    frame=single, 
    % ...
    ]{bat}}{\endminted}
```

and use it with `\usepackage{mydefs}` in your preamble (why not using `\newminted` BTW?)

Next, you write a `mydefs.cwl` file like:

```
\begin{languagebat}#V
\end{languagebat}
```

put it into a directory [described here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040).  You probably have to restart TXS and load your file in order to get it work.

Maybe some TXS expert can confirm this.